# How can i solve this error I get?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2, android-studio-2.3

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processXzsaleDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:8:9-36
>         is also present at [com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
>         Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.

Comment: Please take a look at how to ask a good question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Let me think a little bit. Do you need it ASAP?

Comment: no ,i don't use it

Answer (score 0):

I have found this error when I was using a module in my project.

Actually reason behind this error, I was using **adroid:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"** in the manifest file of my project and module both so it conflict.

to resolve this just add  **tools:replace="android.icon"** in application tag of the manifest file of your module.like this......

```
<application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" Tools:replace="android.icon">
```

### or

remove **adroid:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"** from the manifest file of the module.

Comment: have you used both solutions

Comment: are you adding another module in your project?

Comment: yes i add a Libary ..sneaker..and SupportsRti =false

Comment: is there "android: icon" field in the manifest of your library.

Comment: just remove that line from library or add Tools:replace="android.icon" in application tag of your project  manifest.